# Cannot import package even after I have setup environment variables

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables

Expect to import successfully but

```
signal_game git:(master) ✗ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)
"                                                    
['', '/Users/usr/Documents/Programming\\ Language/Python/Github/EGG', '/Users/usr/Documents/Programming Language/Python/Github/EGG/egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

signal_game git:(master) ✗ python3 train.py                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 6, in <module>
    import egg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'egg'
```

I would like to do this because I want to make some changes in local repositories from git for later committing instead of installing it in python framework which makes it harder to commit.

Comment: You should include the error output you get as part of your question, not a link to a screenshot of console output (that could become a dead link in the future)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run
`pip install egg`

and then run it

## update

Try do this in terminal when you are in the egg folder

`pip install -e .` (may need to uninstall the previous egg)

This will install the package from the current folder and will update when the package got change

Comment: I know this method but I would like to modify this package and commit it on my Github.